# Oracle server side cursor for large data manipulation

Tags: php, oracle

I would like to made server side cursor with oracle database, like this postgresql syntax :

```
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT foo FROM bar";
```

Moreother I need also the exact syntax to fetch properly data like this postgresql syntax :

```
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor
```

After one day of search, I havn't found the proper syntax to do this.

I need to use theses syntax because I have to manage a large amount of row and PDO or oracle native php function aren't able to manage in a proper way the server side cursors.

Thanks for help

Comment: Wow, there are only about a million references in Google on oracle cursor usage - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Comment: Your document is about PL/SQL I try to do this in plain query.